# set Custom Programatically created drawable to radioButton for states

Tags: android, android-custom-view, android-drawable, android-radiobutton, android-custom-drawable

I wanted to set a programatically created drawable to radio button for its checked and unchecked states, but it is not working my code is as follows,

Code to draw a rectangular box,

```
public static GradientDrawable squareView(int backgroundColor, int borderColor)
{
    GradientDrawable shape = new GradientDrawable();
    shape.setShape(GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE);
    //shape.setCornerRadii(new float[] { 8, 8, 8, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0 });
    shape.setColor(backgroundColor);
    shape.setStroke(3, borderColor);
    return shape;
}
```

Code to set programatically created View(squareview) to set as stated to radiobutton,

```
public static void setChecked_Selector(Context context,RadioButton view) {
    try {
        Drawable pressed=squareView(ContextCompat.getColor(context,R.color.colorBlue),ContextCompat.getColor(context,R.color.colorRed));//new BadgeDrawable(context,colorPressed);
        Drawable normal=squareView(ContextCompat.getColor(context,R.color.colorwhite),ContextCompat.getColor(context,R.color.colorRed));

        StateListDrawable states = new StateListDrawable();
        states.addState(new int[]{android.R.attr.state_checked,},pressed);
        states.addState(new int[]{android.R.attr.state_pressed}, pressed);

        states.addState(new int[]{android.R.attr.state_checked, android.R.attr.state_enabled}, pressed);
        states.addState(new int[]{android.R.attr.state_checked, -android.R.attr.state_enabled}, pressed);

        states.addState(new int[]{}, normal);
        view.setButtonDrawable(states);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

Comment: You missed the state for unchecked. Isn't that?

Comment: states.addState(new int[]{android.R.attr.state_checked, -android.R.attr.state_enabled}, pressed);

Comment: that was for uncheck condition

Comment: Isn't it for `checked: true` and `enabled:false`? I think you need something like `(new int[]{-android.R.attr.state_checked}, pressed)` or `(new int[]{-android.R.attr.state_checked, android.R.attr.state_enabled}, pressed)`

Comment: @Rehan, i tried your code as well but didn't worked. any way thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a little work around, I realized that the issue is the drawable does not have any size. I'm not sure what size you should give but just adding following line makes your `RadioButton` visible:

```
shape.setSize(50, 50);
```

I would suggest to put appropriate size for it in `dimens.xml` and use this instead:

```
int size = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.radio_button_size);
shape.setSize(size, size);
```